# Quiero cerrar el flujo en un metodo boolean

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

He creado un método que me va a retornar **true** o **false** dependiendo de los checkbox marcados en un Jpanel. Ese retorno lo usare para escribir Strings de manera que si es valor es false imprime un mensaje y de ser verdadero otro.

```
public boolean estabilidad() {
    boolean estable = false;
    if (establecheck.isSelected() && hipoTAcheck.isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Estable no es compatible con HipoTA ");
    } else if (establecheck.isSelected()) {
        estable=true;
    } else if (hipoTAcheck.isSelected()){
        estable=false;
    }
    return estable;
}
```

Cuando coinciden 2 check como en el **primer If** salta un mensaje de que no son compatibles pero luego el flujo continua y retorna false, con lo que el programa sigue imprimiendo un mensaje incorrecto o que no viene a cuenta.

¿Como puedo hacer para que una vez salte ese mensaje, el programa no continúe hasta que el usuario desmarque la casilla correspondiente?

El metodo que devuelve los Strings en funcion de la variable booleana obtenida es

```
public String mensajeEstabilidad(boolean estable) {
    String mensaje;
    if(estable==true){
        mensaje="Paciente generalmente estable durante los tratamientos \ncon " +
                "buena tolerancia a las sesiones y sin incidencias a reportar";
    }else {
        mensaje="Paciente inestable, con incidencias reportadas en cuanto a tolerancia \nde " +
                "las sesiones. Manifestado con sintomatología asociada a la hipotensión";
    }
    return mensaje;
}
```

Comment: podrias hacer una condicional en la cual el checkbox que que este activado `if( checkbox1.isSelected());` desactive al otro `checkbox2. setEnabled(false);`  de esa manera te aseguras que el usuario active un checkbox

Comment: Es mejor prevenir que el usuario cometa el error, a permitir que lo cometa para después pedirle que lo corrija. Al ocurrir el evento de selección habría que deshabilitar los que no deben seleccionarse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la manera que me dices esta seria la solucion que yo veo para detener el flujo del metodo y es usando una excepcion.

```
public boolean estabilidad() {
  boolean estable = false;
  if (establecheck.isSelected() && hipoTAcheck.isSelected()) {
  //Lanazamos la excepcion
     throw new Exception("Aqui ponemos el mensaje");
  } else if (establecheck.isSelected()) {
     estable=true;
  } else if (hipoTAcheck.isSelected()){
     estable=false;
 }
 return estable;
}
```

y ya fuera de tu metodo, donde lo estes llamando controlas la excepcion e incorporas lo que quieras hacer.

```
public void Ejemplo(){
    try{
       //si aqui falla el metodo todo el flujo del try no sera procesado y se lanzara al catch
       estabilidad()
    }catch(Exception ex){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.GetMessage());
       //y aqui si quieres cerramos la app o cualquier cosa
    }
}
```

Comment: Correcto, pero en el caso primero de ambas seleccionadas, salta el mensaje JOptionPane y retorna un valor, ya sea false o true. La cuestión es que en ese caso no quiero que me retorne nada, simplemente que se cierre el flujo, o se cierre el programa, o no se, pero que no avance porque entonces el mensaje que obtengo con ese valor true o false no tiene sentido

Comment: Tengo un metodo que al pasarle ese resultado booleano, me devuelve un String si es false, y otro String si es true. En el caso de que ambas dos estén seleccionadas ese método ya no me sirve

Comment: Entonces lo que podrias hacer es lanzar una excepcion con **Throw new Exception()**

Comment: @JoseL. ya te he puesto el ejemplo en la respuesta

Comment: He visto gracias. Estoy intentándolo como dices y consigo el mensaje de la excepción pero igualmente en el metodo **estabilidad()** a pesar de poner throw new Exception no se para y retorna false.

Comment: Ya está creo. Lo he hecho como me dices solo que al invocar el método el IDE me ha añadido **throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage());** Esto paraliza el programa y a partir de ahi, en el condicional **if** he añadido aparte del throw  que indicabas, un reset de los checkbox con setSelected(false). Ahora ya salta el aviso de que solo 1 y no sigue hasta que solo 1 esta marcado. Gracias!